# Can Ajax determine which div to update

Tags: jquery, ajax

When performing user login, if the login succeeds, I would like to display a message in a certain div. However, if the login fails, another message is displayed in another div. Is it possible to determine the content of Ajax's 'returnData' and update the appropriate div accordingly? For example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.submitForm').ajaxForm({
    success: function(returnData) {
      if (returnData == '...') { // (or: len(returnData) == ... whatever)
          $('#someDiv').html(returnData);
      } else {
          $('#otherDiv').html(returnData);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What a prompt response! Thanks, and I'll give it a try.

Comment: You may also want to consider implementing the `error` function to display an error message upon error.

Comment: No, I use python on Google App Engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is certainly possible to do that. You're using the pseudocode:

```
if returnData == '...'
    $('#someDiv').html(returnData);
else
    $('#otherDiv').html(returnData);
```

But what it actually would be is not far off:

```
if(returnData == '...')  // note the parentheses
    $('#someDiv').html(returnData);
else
    $('#otherDiv').html(returnData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Certainly.  Of course, the return data must support passing back the success or failure of the login request.  Your code looks quite correct, under this assumption.  Have you tried it?